# Can't edit images

Tags: cropping

Two days ago I discovered a huge problem with my Wordpress media editor. I just can't edit any image because it doesn't appear. Wordpress shows only small icon of broken picture... I was looking for the problem and now I'm pretty sure functions.php file causes my problem. I realized when I remove functions.php - problem disappear too. But what is strange - editor doesn't work when functions.php is EMPTY.

I tried everything. I turned off all of my plugins, but I can't rid of my functions.php, because It's too important for me. On the other hand the problem with images is really irritating...

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Removing functions.php might be too aggressive. What is there in relation to 'media' or 'attachment' or 'image' that might be influencing your installation?

Comment: In functions.php there are several functions related to 'images' like thumbnails. However I think functions don't cause the problem because, how I mentioned, when I make empty functions.php file the problem immediately appears.

Comment: I solved the problem: it was bad formatting of functions.php file - UTF-8. When i turned it to UTF-8 without BOM my problem just disappear.

Comment: Muppet, you could submit your solution as an answer and select it as correct, if you wish. For closure.

Answer (score 1):

I solved the problem: it was bad formatting of functions.php file - UTF-8. When i turned it to UTF-8 without BOM my problem just disappear.

Comment: Please mark this as the accepted answer.

Comment: How did you changed formatting?